# What is the best data structure for dynamically populating a dropdown menu?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-structures, drop-down-menu

I have 4 values that I am correlating, represented by this database table:

[image: menu tree database table]

I'm searching for a data structure in C# that I can essentially have *one* key with *three* values per entry, the `Level` fields being the keys in this case.

This would be the relationship between these values:

> 0  -->  (0, "Top-level", "")
>   
>   1  -->  (0, "Submenu", "")
>   
>   2  -->  (1, "asdf", "http://www.asdf.com")
>   
>   2  -->  (1, "qwerty", "http://www.qwerty.com")

Note that the keys *would **not** be unique.*

---

With the example database information above, I would be creating this nested `asp:MenuItem`:

```
<asp:MenuItem Text = "Top-level">
    <asp:MenuItem Text = "Submenu">
        <asp:MenuItem Text = "asdf" NavigateUrl = "http://www.asdf.com" />
        <asp:MenuItem Text = "qwerty" NavigateUrl = "http://www.qwerty.com" />
    </asp:MenuItem>
</asp:MenuItem>
```

...with a nasty C# data structure something like this:

```
// this is crazy!
SortedDictionary<int, SortedDictionary<int, KeyValuePair<string, string>>
```

---

There is obviously **a lot** more detail involved in dynamically populating a dropdown menu, such as [tree traversal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal), *but for now I am mainly concerned with having the right structure to start with*.

Comment: Why not a simple `DataTable`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used a class structure to do this; dictionaries are going to be hard because it can be many levels deep.  A class does this much better, because it can support infinite nested levels:

```
public class MenuItem
{
   public string Text { get; set; }
   public string NavigateUrl { get; set; }
   .
   .

   public List<MenuItem> Children { get; set; }

}
```

And so each menu item can have it's own children, which has it's children, and can support many levels deep.  To generate it requires looping through the root level records, then look for it's children in the data source, and build the collection in a recursive oriented way.

Comment: Thanks @Brian, this is great! This works for iteration with a `for` loop, however to use a `foreach` loop it seems that `IEnumerator` and `IEnumerable` must be implemented. See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322022 for reference.

Comment: It should work as long as you are using foreach with the Children property, which is List<T>, and List<T> implements those interfaces.